# Need more migrate options on Off Topic question

Tags: feature-request, migration

Some of the questions asked here are Off Topic. Bad formualted questions or commercial third party questions can be put on hold without further explaination. But some questions are really good, and shouldn't be closed. they should be migrated to another .SE site.

Currently, the only option we have is StackOverflow and our own meta.

[image]

Some questions, like "[Editing/Setting Mime Types with Powershell?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/81415/6382)" could fit on SO, but is probably better off at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) where they already have 6000+ questions regarding IIS.

[image]

Is it possible to add more sites to the migrate option list when calling a close vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree, sometimes the question is off-topic that is a reasonable question, but it doesn't go on Meta, or even on any related Stack Exchange. These are some tweaks that I think we can make as moderator, Benny! I know it's been out there as a feature request before.

In the off-topic flag, I would like to see at least:

- SuperUser
- StackOverflow
- ServerFault

I agree it doesn't make sense to close a great question just because it's not in the right area.

Comment: I have more options available. Not sure if it is because I am a mod, or a function of which other sites in the network I am a member of. Something to follow up on.