# "Close as Off-Topic" Reasons

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Can we discuss opening up the "Close as Off-Topic > Off-topic because... > This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" section?

Right now if a question belongs on another SE site other than Meta, you can't use this option and have to provide a custom "Other" reason to close as off-topic. There is a specific option for StackOverflow, but if the question isn't a programming question, nor about SharePoint, why shouldn't we be able to select a different SE site?

There used to be an option to suggest migration to other sites than Meta and SO.

Can we bring this back?

Comment: I will try to make another off topic/migrate option available tomorrow when I'm on a PC and not a pad... Stay tuned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very good suggestion and would be happy to implement more migration options. This has also [been asked for before](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/q/931/6382), and the suggestion then was:

- StackOverflow
- Serverfault
- Super User

There is a limit of three Off topic > Migration options where two spots are already taken by Meta and StackOverflow.

Personally I think that questions which could be migrated to Super User is on topic, provided that the question regards SharePoint.

My suggestion is that we add Serverfault as the third migration option, and in all other cases, we need to continue flagging if we need to migrate elsewhere.

Please keep flagging if you see questions posted at the wrong Stackexchange site. It helps us and other get the right answer to the question they have and keeps our Q&A On Topic!

Comment: Would be interesting to know how often Meta is actually used to migrate a question though! Seems like not the most used option :)

Comment: @RobertLindgren See migrated away. Especially page two. It's a lot of questions going to our meta :-)

Comment: Valid point, but in the last 90 days, there where 1 ;)

Comment: Upvote on this suggestion. I've had several questions that should better be moved to superuser.com.